# Highcharts axis does not show properly values when numbers are so small

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've just found this weird behavior with Highchart axis values when the series are next to zero:

```
series: [{
  name: 'Tokyo',
  data: [0.0000000001,0.0000000002,0.0000000001,0.0000000002,0.0000000001,0.0000000002,0.0000000001,0.0000000002,0.0000000001,0.0000000002,0.0000000001,0.0000000002]
}]
```

See it: http://jsfiddle.net/u29mpdnk/

But is being showed properly when series are next to another number:

```
series: [{
  name: 'Tokyo',
  data: [12.0000000001,12.0000000002,12.0000000001,12.0000000002,12.0000000001,12.0000000002,12.0000000001,12.0000000002,12.0000000001,12.0000000002,12.0000000001,12.0000000002]
}]
```

See it: http://jsfiddle.net/m3zohat1/1/

Looks like a bug, isn't it? Any workaround?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use yAxis [label's formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.formatter) and then use [Highcharts.dateFormat](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.numberFormat)

```
labels:{
                tickInterval: 0.0000000001,
                formatter:function(){
                    return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 11,'.');
                }
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/u29mpdnk/1/